# Automated mailing list - PHP

Tags: php, email

i have an application on my site where people can sign up to receive newsletters, and then someone in a paid group can write and send one immediately to everybody who signed up...

...meaning that i need an efficient way to loop through my database of subscribers and mail them copies of the email using php.

clearly, there is the mail() function....i could put that in a loop...is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest finding a way to loop through, and remembering who you mailed already, because if it becomes a large list of people, you script might end and you'd have to reload it.

I have done it once using AJAX, gave me a great way to track where I was in the sending proces. Counted how many people to mail, put the id's in an array, had javascript loop and make seperate calls to a php-mail-page...

-edit-
You can have a script in php, with a simple while loop, but then you should add a check in the DB to see if a mail was already sent to one person. If the script exceeds memory usage, just reload the page, and it will only sent to the ones that haven't received it yet...

Comment: send one mail per recipient instead of just bcc it?

Comment: yeah, makes them feel special. Gives you the ability to adress them personally in the mail itself, too. Plus, the mail is less likely to be tagged as spam... or so I have been told

Answer (score 3):

PEAR's [mail queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue)?

> The Mail_Queue class puts mails in a
>   temporary container, waiting to be fed
>   to the MTA (Mail Transport Agent), and
>   sends them later (e.g. a certain
>   amount of mails every few minutes) by
>   crontab or in other way.

Comment: yeah ive heard about that too actually...i tried installing pear and using it but had a little bit of trouble (my site travels between subdomain names, and having a stationary library gets confusing for me)...is it hard to use and figure out though in general?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the BCC header option and send one email with a Blind Carbon Copy list of all the subscribers.
So build the BCC string in the loop and send one email using mail()

Snippet from the PHP manual...

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Replace 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' with $mySubscribersList

Comment: i feel you on this, would it leave ANY trace of other people? because i have their security to worry about...

Comment: BCC is fine for that, it's what it's designed for. Each person appears to get a separate email, without anyone elses details in the header. Unlike CC.

Answer (score 1):

Following on @paulbm's answer, why not create an alias on your server that points to all current email addresses? A short procmail script can prevent anyone other than one authorized sender using the alias.

It'd make mailing's easy, and rebuilding the list with new/changed email address would be pretty simple, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try phplist ([Homepage](http://www.phplist.org)) if you need a full featured newsletter and mailinglist manager